# SOAP and Spring

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

I've just finished reading about SOAP via Spring-WS in "Spring in Action", 2nd edition, by Craig Walls from Manning Publications Co. They write about Contract First, much like the Spring docs, with making a message and method XML and then transforming that to XSD and then again to WSDL, while wiring up the marshalling and service path in Spring.

I must admit, I'm not convinced. Why is this a better path than, let's say, making a service interface and generating my service based on that interface? That's quite close to defining my REST @Controllers in Spring3. Do I have options of going a path like this with making SOAP webservices with Spring?

Also: I'd like to duplicate an already existing webservice. I have its WSDL and I can have my service placed instead of it. Is this recommended at all? If so, what's the recommended approach?

Cheers

```
Nik
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you must have your wires crossed.

Contract first means defining a WSDL, and then creating Java code to support this WSDL.

Contract last means creating your Java code, and generating a WSDL later.

The danger with contract last is if your WSDL is automatically generated from your Java code, and you refactor your Java code, this causes your WSDL to change.

[Spring-WS only supports contract first](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/why-contract-first.html)

> 2.3.1. Fragility
>
> As mentioned earlier, the
>   contract-last development style
>   results in your web service contract
>   (WSDL and your XSD) being generated
>   from your Java contract (usually an
>   interface). If you are using this
>   approach, you will have no guarantee
>   that the contract stays constant over
>   time. Each time you change your Java
>   contract and redeploy it, there might
>   be subsequent changes to the web
>   service contract.
>
> Aditionally, not all SOAP stacks
>   generate the same web service contract
>   from a Java contract. This means
>   changing your current SOAP stack for a
>   different one (for whatever reason),
>   might also change your web service
>   contract.
>
> When a web service contract changes,
>   users of the contract will have to be
>   instructed to obtain the new contract
>   and potentially change their code to
>   accommodate for any changes in the
>   contract.
>
> In order for a contract to be useful,
>   it must remain constant for as long as
>   possible. If a contract changes, you
>   will have to contact all of the users
>   of your service, and instruct them to
>   get the new version of the contract.

Comment: I am aware of that, but in my view, if I have a defined interface for the SOAP service, that is just as likely to change as my XSD and thus my WSDL.

Comment: The point is that the WSDL+Schema is the interface between client and server, and therefore it should be maintained as the primary definition, with the code following on from that.

Answer (score 3):

Toolkit's point about Java interfaces being more brittle is correct, but I think there's more.

Just like there's an object-relational impedance mismatch, there's also an object-XML mismatch.  The Spring web service docs do a fine job of explaining how collections and the rest can make generating an XML document from a Java or .NET class problematic.

If you take the Spring approach and start with a schema you'll be better off.  It'll be more stable, and it'll allow "duck typing".  Clients can ignore elements that they don't need, so you can change the schema by adding new elements without affecting them.

Comment: Wouldn't that be equally true if I add to my interface, I would still retain compatibility?

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't affect the existing messages in your WSDL.  But your interface does change if you have Java objects as parameters or return values in your interface, and you make a change to one of those.